# UserForm: в TextBox отобразить сумму значений двух других TextBox

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
C = A + B
TextBox3.Text = C
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
End
End Sub
Public Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim A As Integer
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
Dim B As Integer
End Sub
Public Sub TextBox3_Change()
Dim C As Integer
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается отобразить результат...

Comment: Исправил заголовок

Answer (score 1):

В элементах *UserForm* значения хранятся в текстовом виде. Для суммирования данные нужно преобразовать в числовые.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim A As Long, B As Long, C As Long
    A = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    B = Val(TextBox2.Text)
    C = A + B
    TextBox3.Text = C
End Sub
```

`Long` - целое. Если предполагается суммировать и дробные числа, то нужно использовать тип `Double` и при преобразовании вместо `Val` применять оператор `CDbl`

Можно без использования переменных.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox3.Text = CDbl(TextBox1.Text) + CDbl(TextBox2.Text)
End Sub
```

В варианте с дробными числами желательно добавить проверку суммируемых значений, иначе при записанных нечисловых данных получим ошибку:

```
If IsNumeric(A) End IsNumeric(B) Then...
```

В варианте с целыми числами можно обойтись без проверки - `Val` примет только левую числовую часть, а если таковая отсутствует - `Val("text") = 0`